# Some questions about Banach Tarski proof

Tags: group-theory

Banach-Tarski proof as been the topic of a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s86-Z-CbaHA) by the well-known Youtube channel VSauce but there were some parts that I didn't understand. So I went reading for the proof on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox), and I didn't understand the same parts too. It's about the countable infinity of "poles".

Here is a quick overview of the proof :

- The infinite group with two genrators $\{A, B\}$ is called the free group $F$
- Each element $X$ of $F$ can be bijectively mapped to a string $s(X)$ made of $a, b, a^{-1}, b^{-1}$ with no $aa^{-1}, a^{-1}a, bb^{-1}, b^{-1}b$ substring
- If we note $\{x*\}$ the strings starting with $x$, and $e$ the empty string, then :

  $F = s^{-1}(\{a*\} \cup \{b*\} \cup \{a^{-1}*\} \cup \{b^{-1}*\} \cup \{e\})$

  $F = A^{-1}s^{-1}(\{a*\}) \cup s^{-1}(\{a^{-1}*\})$

  $F = B^{-1}s^{-1}(\{b*\}) \cup s^{-1}(\{b^{-1}*\})$
- One can chose two rotations $R$ and $T$ such that the action of their generated group $H$ on $\mathbb{S}_2$ is isomorphic to $F$.
- If we note $M=\mathbb{S}_2/H$, then the equalities above rewrites as :

  $\mathbb{S}_2 = s^{-1}(\{r*\} \cup \{r^{-1}*\} \cup \{t*\} \cup \{t^{-1}*\} \cup \{e\}) \times M$

  $\mathbb{S}_2 = (R^{-1}s^{-1}(\{r*\}) \cup s^{-1}(\{r^{-1}*\})) \times M$

  $\mathbb{S}_2 = (T^{-1}s^{-1}(\{t*\}) \cup s^{-1}(\{t^{-1}*\})) \times M$

What I don't understand how the poles are a problem. First the rotations of $H$ will have a countable infinity of poles $P$. Those cannot be elements of $H$ since there would then be a finite subgroup of $H$ and that's impossible given that $H$ is isomorph to $F$. So these poles are in a different equivalence class i.e. no fixed point string isn't it ? Then in the video, Michael states that there is a countable infinity of poles. But isn't the set of poles on the sphere $P \times M$ uncountable ? What are those troubles Wikipedia is talking about ?

> In Step 3, we partitioned the sphere into orbits of our group $H$. To streamline the proof, we omitted the discussion of points that are fixed by some rotation; since the paradoxical decomposition of $F$ relies on shifting certain subsets, the fact that some points are fixed might cause some trouble.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The poles are the points of $S^2$ that are left fixed by at least one nontrivial element of $H$. Since $H$ is countable and each element of $H$ has exactly two fixed points, there are countably many poles.

In the presence of fixed points, the fact "every point in $S^2$ can be reached in exactly one way by applying the proper rotation from $H$" that is used in step 3 of the proof as given in Wikipedia is wrong.

Therefore, one needs to get rid of these poles - which happens by the same trick we can use to let a single point disappear as in $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, $n\mapsto n+1$.

Comment: Wait, that's a countable infinity of poles *by orbit* and there is an uncountable infinity of orbits, isn't it ?

Comment: And why is the wikipedia affirmation wrong ? (the quotient does not exists ?)

Comment: @idkwptc If $x$ is a point in $S^2$ and we havve $hx=x$ then if $x$ can be reached "by applying the proper rotation" $h_1\in H$, say, then this is not unique because $h_2=hh_1$ does the same. Therefore the claim "reached in *exactly* one way" becomes wrong. We need to classify "the $h$ belonging to $x$" by its word structure, but $h_1$ and $h_2$ may differ in this respect.

Comment: @idkwptc I think I expressed very clearly that there is only a countable number of poles. There is a $2:1$ map from the set of poles to $H\setminus\{1\}$

Comment: I get it now ! It's very weird to explain why but I had in mind that the rotations where relative to the orbit you chose and that they would have been simply rotated from one another but that's not at all the case like the length of the parallels change with the latitude. I will try to give  an explanation of what I didn't understood tomorrow. Thanks !